# Put an HREF in a DIV and give an scroll effect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make a div to be an HREF. I have done it by using javascript...

```
var about = $('#about');
about.click(function(){
        $(location).attr('href', '#quienes-somos');
    });
```

So when I click the "about" div, I can go to the "quienes-somos" div.
However, I need to give the link a scroll effect. I was doing some research and I found that I could use the `animate()` method of jQuery, but I didn't really find out how to apply it to my script.
Thanks so much for any help you can give me!

Mauricio

Comment: Use css animations...

Comment: This answer might help you out https://stackoverflow.com/a/6677069/7804384

Comment: We need more information: Is this href a new page? Why do you even need to put an href on a div, that makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Why don't you wrap the DIV in an anchor? Like `<a href="#quienes-somos"><div>...</div></a>`. Then add `html { scroll-behavior: smooth;}` to your CSS code to perform smooth scrolling on scroll. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/wg8ycmef/3/) for demo.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!!! I will prove to wrap the DIV in an anchor.....

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSS. Finally I made it!!! thanks Sascha!!!!